# How to create a STA thread for F# Asynchronous workflow

Tags: wpf, f#, sta

I am attempting to write a printed form in F# using WPF controls—-and do so in an asynchronous workflow. Being new to this, I can’t figure out how to place the wpf controls, consumed by the F# asynchronous block, on a STA thread, without blocking the main thread.

I have a lot of printed forms and do not want to block the main thread.

How is a STA thread created for the F# asynchronous workflow?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8462558

Comment: And, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154429/apartmentstate-for-dummies

Answer (score 1):

In pure WPF I don't think you have STA - that concept comes from the COM model. What you do have is a specific UI thread that must be used for communicating with the UI. To get that thread you can use [`SynchronizationContext.Current`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current?view=net-6.0) property when you are certain you are on the UI thread (e.g. in an event handler). Note: If `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null` then you will be running in the thread pool rather than on the UI thread.

If you then pass that `SynchronizationContext` object into your `async {}` code, you should be able to rejoin the UI thread by calling [`Async.SwitchToContext`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpasync.html#SwitchToContext)

Comment: @tranquility So...how do I create a thread that is not on the UI so wpf controls can be built for printing???

Comment: @AlanWayne Within an `async` block you can use `do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool` to switch to a random background thread.

Comment: The threads in the thread pool are MTA, how do I change that to STA as needed by the controls? Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne Have you tried `Thread.CurrentThread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)` it is documented as throwing `PlatformNotSupportedException` but it returns true for me (.Net 6).